# Combining Examples in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I wish to combine two examples from the OptaPlanner: Task Assignment and Project Job Scheduling

The description of my app:

1. Start with a project that has a set of employees and tasks. (tasks span days / months)
2. Auto-assign employees to tasks of the project.
3. Auto-schedule the tasks to optimize the duration of the project.

In the second step, the employees have skills which the tasks require. Also each task has a list of dependencies that must complete before that task can start.

**I'm looking to generate the employee assignments and task schedule that give the shortest duration of a project, or an approximation.** It seems like this functionality exists in these two examples.

Is combining these examples reasonable or even possible? I'm new to the OptaPlanner. Is there any architectural advice anyone could provide?